# Oracle 11g query took almost 30min to finish but around 5 min in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g

I need to produce a details report of user that using prepaid.

Basically I have 2 tables. TBL_USER and also TBL_PREPAID_DETAILS

tbl_user only list the users while tbl_prepaid_details will have all the prepaid information such as debit, credit, balance, total topup.

The report will be produced something like this:-

```
FULLNAME USER_ID NEW_BALANCE CREATED DEPOSIT DEBIT TOTAL_DEPOSIT
USER1 1 250 21/05/2011 500 250 1000
USER2 2 250 21/05/2011 500 250 1000
USER3 3 250 21/05/2011 500 250 1000
USER4 4 250 21/05/2011 500 250 1000
```

Before this I'm using SQL server for database but for the year 2012/2013 we need to migrate from SQL server to Oracle 11g.

From the previous sql query (SQL Server), I come out with below query (Oracle 11g). I can get the result but it took almost 30min to finish while in SQL server only took around 5min. **Its only 500+ users**

Is it i'm missing something?? Is there any simplified version to speed up the process ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.FULLNAME AS NAME,
                A.USER_ID AS ID,
                B.NAME,

  (SELECT T.NEW_BAL
   FROM
     (SELECT NEW_BAL,
             USER_ID
      FROM TBL_PREPAID_DETAILS
      WHERE DATE_INSERT BETWEEN '01/01/2010' AND '14/11/2012'
      ORDER BY PREPAID_DETAIL_ID DESC) T
   WHERE T.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
     AND ROWNUM = 1) AS NEW_BALANCE,

  (SELECT T2.DATE_INSERT
   FROM
     (SELECT DATE_INSERT,
             USER_ID
      FROM TBL_PREPAID_DETAILS
      WHERE DATE_INSERT BETWEEN '01/01/2010' AND '14/11/2012'
      ORDER BY DATE_INSERT DESC)T2
   WHERE T2.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
     AND ROWNUM = 1) AS DATE_INSERT,

  (SELECT T3.PREV_BAL
   FROM
     (SELECT PREV_BAL,
             USER_ID
      FROM TBL_PREPAID_DETAILS
      WHERE DATE_INSERT BETWEEN '01/01/2010' AND '14/11/2012'
      ORDER BY PREPAID_DETAIL_ID ASC)T3
   WHERE T3.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
     AND ROWNUM = 1) AS DEPOSIT,

  (SELECT SUM(T4.CREDIT)
   FROM
     (SELECT CREDIT,
             USER_ID
      FROM TBL_PREPAID_DETAILS
      WHERE DATE_INSERT BETWEEN '01/01/2010' AND '14/11/2012'
      ORDER BY PREPAID_DETAIL_ID ASC)T4
   WHERE T4.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
     AND ROWNUM = 1) AS DEBIT,

  (SELECT SUM(T5.DEBIT + T5.PREV_BAL)
   FROM
     (SELECT DEBIT,
             PREV_BAL,
             USER_ID
      FROM TBL_PREPAID_DETAILS
      WHERE DATE_INSERT BETWEEN '01/01/2010' AND '14/11/2012'
      ORDER BY PREPAID_DETAIL_ID ASC)T5
   WHERE T5.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
     AND ROWNUM = 1) AS TOTAL_DEPOSIT
FROM TBL_USER A
LEFT JOIN TBL_PREPAID_DETAILS C ON A.USER_ID = C.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_ORGANIZATION_INFO B ON A.ORGANIZATION_ID = B.ORGANIZATION_ID
WHERE C.DATE_INSERT BETWEEN '01/01/2010' AND '14/11/2012'
  AND (A.USER_ID NOT IN ('xxx',
                         'xxx',
                         'xxx'))
GROUP BY A.FULLNAME,
         A.USER_ID,
         C.DATE_INSERT,
         B.NAME
ORDER BY A.FULLNAME;
```

Comment: What index(es) exist?  What are the query plans in both databases?  Are the statistics on the various objects accurate?  Is `DATE_INSERT` a date or a string?  If it is a date, why are you comparing it against a string?

Comment: Other notes: Never use `BETWEEN` for date/time/timestamps, perhaps _especially_ on SQL Server (yes, I see you're moving...); always use an exclusive upper bound (`'<'`).  Never prefix object (or column) names with their types, it's noise, and may make certain types of refactoring awkward later; in the case of columns, always name them so type is 'obvious' (eg, `insertedOn`, or similar).  Could we get your table definitions, and sample data for those expected results?  Also, you're not ordering by a consistent attribute, which makes me twitchy...

Comment: This will run faster on both systems if you use an `OVER` clause -- Then you won't need the `GROUP BY` statement.  If you need an example I could write you one if you posted the full table definitions.

Comment: Please post the execution plans from both systems.

Comment: @JustinCave DATE_INSERT. My bad, need to change to TO_DATE first

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse will change the between to (>= and <=)

Comment: .... @skycrew - well, okay, but just note that dealing with an inclusive upper-bound (`<=`) can be pretty awkward, especially when dealing with timestamps.  It's usually best to think of ends of ranges (whether stored or searched by) as being less than the first instant something _else_ became valid.  So, in the case of expiration dates, store the first day the customer is no longer valid, not the last day they will be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this page for general overview help on Oracle Tuning.  [Overall Oracle Tuning Page](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_sql_tune.htm)

Oracle provides a great deal of tools to tune performance, including what indexes could be added to improve a particular query. It is one of the first things I do when I encounter a slow running query. In your case, I would consider running an explain plan on your query and see what Oracle recommends. Here is the documentation on running an explain plan. [Oracle Explain Plan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm)

Comment: thanks for the info. I will try to run the oracle explain plan